# How can i set auto redirect if cookie was set before in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

Halo, i'm very confuse with this condition.. i already set cookies if user was regist or login before.. but if i refresh the page.. the cookie was not read and not directed to page that i set before

my code is

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useStore } from "../src/redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { authService } from "../src/services/AuthServices";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { SSRProvider } from "react-bootstrap";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const store = useStore(pageProps.initialReduxState);
  const dataAuth = authService.isLogin();
  const router = useRouter();
  const routeList = ["/login"];
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dataAuth) {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <SSRProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Provider>
    </SSRProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

does anyone can help ?